# Algorithms for casual feature selection for continuous Y

Tags: python, feature-selection, feature-extraction, feature-construction

Currently I have been trying to find some good algorithms for feature selection. Using correlation or other non casual type of method will not be the right way to do a feature selection. I'm am searching for aglorithms in python or libraries that use casual effects for feature selection. Currently there are only for binary outcomes, I'm searching for a regression problem so it must be continuous.

"Causality-Guided Feature Selection"

Comment: What exactly do you mean saying „causal“? Does Ridge/Lasso count as non-causal?

Comment: @Peter Unfortunately not, Ridge and Lasso doesn't explain casuality.

What I mean by my question is the following:
Y = aX + bZ => for sipmplicity let's take they are linear
Does X explain Y ?
Does Z explain Y?
Does Z explain Y through X?
Or does Y explain X or Z than the model is literally off.
I want to respond to these questions, not just by using correlation which is false.

Comment: Geri, are you able to use Granger causality test? Or maybe the predictive power score? https://towardsdatascience.com/rip-correlation-introducing-the-predictive-power-score-3d90808b9598

Comment: Granger causality is for time series data https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality. I‘m not aware that there is a test etc to detect causality in the narrow sense. So when you mean „identification“ and not only „exogenous variation“ when you speak about causality, things get little messy http://fmwww.bc.edu/EC-P/wp957.pdf

Comment: Does the Paul Holland's motto given in this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2245/statistics-and-causal-inference answer your question?

Comment: I personally found this guys that had some great examples.  So will search for Partial correlation algorithms that might work for me. They explain everything with examples. Still don't know if this is a good lead but trying, I'll keep you posted 

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/350206337_Variable_Selection_for_Fault_Detection_Based_on_Causal_Discovery_Methods_Analysis_of_an_Actual_Industrial_Case

Answer (score 0):

The best resource I've found for ready-made causal inference implementations is this [Github repository](https://github.com/rguo12/awesome-causality-algorithms). I've personally used R and Python implementations of Tetrad to create a graph of the features, and then code an additional step to get variables within the Markov Boundary with respect to the target variable for feature selection. You could also use variants of the PC algorithm to achieve the same thing. There's also this [review paper](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fgene.2019.00524/full) that outlines a lot of the algorithms for different cases.

Comment: Thank you. The PC algorithm is a partial response for me (no pun intended). So I will keep working on this and keep you posted